# Laravel маршруты

Tags: laravel

Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема.Если я правильно понимаю данный вью будет загружаться только после того как будет POST запрос?

```
class UsersController extends Controller{

        public function create(){

            $data['title'] = 'Create user';

            return view('users.create_user',$data); 
        }
}

<form method="post">
        <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        <input type="text" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

Route::post('users/create','UsersController@create');

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:
```

Comment: Поменял маршрут на Route::any('users/create','UsersController@create');  и заработало

Comment: Ошибка возникает когда? Когда нажимаете на Save в форме?

Comment: Нет.Просто обращаюсь к данному методу и возникает ошибка.

Comment: Если вы в браузере пытаетесь зайти по адресу "<ваш сайт>/users/create", то будет выполнен поиск контроллера для GET метода, так как обычный запрос по адресу - это GET. А вот когда на Save нажмете, тогда уже POST будет. 
Хорошей практикой в данном случае будет создать один метод для отображения формы по GET запросу, и второй - для обработки сохранения после нажатия на Save.

Comment: Ага я так и понял изначально.А если использовать Any? Это получается метод будет вызван при реквестах любого типа?

Comment: да, но так лучше не делать.

Answer (score 4):

Вы же выводите форму, тогда нужно использовать GET, из браузера же ломитесь по адресу "`/users/create`"

А вообще лучше сделать ресурс

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

И не писать потом кучу роутов руками, достаточно будет описать нужный метод в контроллере.

http://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Ну я только начал изучение Laravel,поэтому всех тонкостей не знаю!

Comment: @quaresma89 для этого и создан этот сайт :)